# How can I pull cookies in teams plugin https://teams.microsoft.com/

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-teams, httpcookie

```
     public ActionResult Create()
    
 CookieOptions localcookie = new CookieOptions();
            localcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            localcookie.HttpOnly = true;
            localcookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            localcookie.Domain= "https://localhost:44328";
            Response.Cookies.Append("username", "mehmetlocal", localcookie);
            Response.Cookies.Append("password", "deytek123*", localcookie);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            CookieOptions defaulCookie = new CookieOptions();
            defaulCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            defaulCookie.HttpOnly = true;
            defaulCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; 
            Response.Cookies.Append("username", "mehmetdefault", defaulCookie);
            Response.Cookies.Append("password", "123*", defaulCookie);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            CookieOptions teamsCookie = new CookieOptions();
            teamsCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            teamsCookie.HttpOnly = true;
            teamsCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            teamsCookie.Domain= "https://teams.microsoft.com/";
            Response.Cookies.Append("username", "mehmethttpsteams", teamsCookie);
            Response.Cookies.Append("password", "123*", teamsCookie);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            CookieOptions teamsCookie1 = new CookieOptions();
            teamsCookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            teamsCookie1.HttpOnly = true;
            teamsCookie1.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            teamsCookie1.Domain = "teams.microsoft.com";
            Response.Cookies.Append("username", "mehmetteam1", teamsCookie1);
            Response.Cookies.Append("password", "123*", teamsCookie1);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            CookieOptions ngRok = new CookieOptions();
            ngRok.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            ngRok.HttpOnly = true;
            ngRok.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            ngRok.Domain = "https://da98-88-250-230-175.ngrok.io";
            Response.Cookies.Append("username", "mehmetngrok", ngRok);
            Response.Cookies.Append("password", "123*", ngRok); 
            /////////////////////////////////////
            CookieOptions ngRok1 = new CookieOptions();
            ngRok1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            ngRok1.HttpOnly = true;
            ngRok1.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            ngRok1.Domain = "da98-88-250-230-175.ngrok.io";
            Response.Cookies.Append("username", "mehmetngrokv2", ngRok1);
            Response.Cookies.Append("password", "123*", ngRok1);
   return View();
        }
```

[image]

```
  [HttpPost]
   // [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        string username = Request.Cookies["username"];
        string password = Request.Cookies["password"];
        string test = Request.Cookies["test"];

        try
        {
            return View(user);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I run ngRok with this command =ngrok http https://localhost:44347 -host-header="localhost:44347"

[HttpGet] I define my cookies in Create Action, but when I click the Create button, Request.Cookies are empty. https://teams.microsoft.com/ cookies are empty on this site
But I can pull cookies on ngrok's site.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the cookie is being blocked? Have you tried to add microsoft.com and microsoftonline.com in the "Sites that can always use cookies"?

Comment: @Mehmet - Are you able to get the cookies outside of Teams ? We have tried it but it's not working outside as well. We tried the last way which you have mentioned to set the Cookies ?  Which is working for you ?

Comment: @Mehment - We tried it outside the Teams with local host domain but it's not working at all. Is it working for you ?

Comment: I can access cookies in local but not in teams web

Comment: We tried like below, but we cannot see cookies on ngrok's site as well. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj1KQ.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FkYy.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSvgK.png
Could you please let us know what we are missing and help us in reproing the issue?

Comment: Could you please help with the above ask?

Comment: I couldn't solve it either

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same, we will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you follow the instructions here to set the correct SameSite attribute on your cookies:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/samesite-cookie-update

Otherwise, they will not get persisted correctly when your site is loaded in a cross-origin iframe (i.e. what Teams does).